# Trouble balancing a binary search tree using AVL

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I'm unable to identify where I'm going wrong with my AVL implementation for balancing an existing binary search tree. I'm not getting any errors but my binary search tree does not come out to be properly balanced. After insertion, my binary search tree looks like (it would be prudent here to mention that my display_keys method gives us a visualization that is rotated by 90 degrees):

```
        ∅
    The-Dreamers
            ∅
        Saint-Laurent
                ∅
            Pierrot-le-Fou
                    ∅
                Contempt
                        Cold-War
                    Before-Sunrise
                        ∅
Basic-Instinct
    ∅
```

This is correct as it seems be to be following the rules for a BST.
But after calling the `BalanceTree()` method on my binary search tree, I seem to get:

```
        ∅
    The-Dreamers
        Saint-Laurent
Pierrot-le-Fou
            Contempt
        Cold-War
            Before-Sunrise
    Basic-Instinct
        ∅
```

which as you can see, is not Balanced. But wait, and here's the catch, if I call `BalanceTree()` again, the tree comes out to be perfectly balanced and `isBSTBalanced` returns True also. After the second call to `BalanceTree()`, our tree looks like:

```
        ∅
    The-Dreamers
        Saint-Laurent
Pierrot-le-Fou
        Contempt
    Cold-War
            Before-Sunrise
        Basic-Instinct
            ∅
```

I am adding the complete source code for my BST class for clarity and if somebody wants to execute the code, *but* I have added a comment (**#Addition of new methods for AVL starts here**) in the BST class to indicate where the methods for AVL start. You need only concern yourself with them. I would like for you help me pinpoint what exactly is going wrong in my code.

```
class BST:

    class TreeNode:
        def __init__(self, key, value, left=None, right=None, parent=None):
            self.key = key
            self.value = value
            self.left = left
            self.right = right
            self.parent = parent
            self.height = 1


    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.size = 0

    def __len__(self):
        return self.size 

    def insert(self, key, value):
        if self.root == None:
            self.root = self.TreeNode(key, value)
        else:
            self._insert(key, value, self.root)

        self.size += 1

    def _insert(self, key, value, curr_node):
        if key < curr_node.key:
            if curr_node.left is not None:
                self._insert(key, value, curr_node.left)
            else:
                curr_node.left = self.TreeNode(key, value, parent=curr_node)
        elif key > curr_node.key:
            if curr_node.right is not None:
                self._insert(key, value, curr_node.right)
            else:
                curr_node.right = self.TreeNode(key, value, parent=curr_node)

    def search(self, key):
        if self.root:
            found = self._search(key, self.root)
            if found:                
                return found.value
            else:
                return None
        else:
            return None

    def _search(self, key, curr_node):
        if not curr_node:
            return None
        elif curr_node.key == key:
            return curr_node
        elif key < curr_node.key:
            return self._search(key, curr_node.left)
        else:
            return self._search(key, curr_node.right)

    def find_min(self):
        curr = self.root
        while curr.left is not None:
            curr = curr.left
        return curr

    def find(self, node):
        curr = node
        while curr.left is not None:
            curr = curr.left
        return curr

    def delete(self, key):
        node_to_remove = self._search(key, self.root)
        if node_to_remove.left is None and node_to_remove.right is None:
            #Then we identify this as a leaf node
            if node_to_remove is node_to_remove.parent.left:
                #Setting the parent's reference to this to None
                node_to_remove.parent.left = None 
            elif node_to_remove is node_to_remove.parent.right:
                node_to_remove.parent.right = None


        #2nd Case --> Two child
        elif node_to_remove.left and node_to_remove.right:
            minimum = self.find(node_to_remove.right)
            self.delete(minimum.key) #We will still have a ref to this node afterwards
            node_to_remove.key, node_to_remove.value = minimum.key, minimum.value

        #3rd Case -> One child
        else:
            if node_to_remove.left:
                node_to_remove.left.parent = node_to_remove.parent
                node_to_remove.parent.left = node_to_remove.left
            elif node_to_remove.right:
                node_to_remove.right.parent = node_to_remove.parent
                node_to_remove.parent.right = node_to_remove.right

    def traversal(self, root):
        res = []
        if root:
            res = self.traversal(root.left) 
            res.append(root)
            res = res + self.traversal(root.right)
        return res

    def inorder_traversal(self, root):
        if root:
            self.inorder_traversal(root.left)
            print(root.key)
            self.inorder_traversal(root.right)

    #Addition of new methods for AVL starts here
    
    def display_keys(self, node, space='\t', level=0):
        """
        Allows us to visualize the tree (albiet rotated by 90 degrees)
        """
        # print(node.key if node else None, level)

        # If the node is empty
        if node is None:
            print(space*level + '∅')
            return   

        # If the node is a leaf 
        if node.left is None and node.right is None:
            print(space*level + str(node.key))
            return

        # If the node has children
        self.display_keys(node.right, space, level+1)
        print(space*level + str(node.key))
        self.display_keys(node.left,space, level+1)    

    def height(self):
        return self._height(self.root)

    def _height(self, curr_node):
        if curr_node is None:
            return -1 #since we are counting number of edges, we will return -1 
        else:
            return 1 + max(self._height(curr_node.left), self._height(curr_node.right))


    def isBSTBalanced(self):
        return self._isBSTBalanced(self.root)


    def _isBSTBalanced(self, curr_node):
        if curr_node is None:
            return True
        hleft_subtree = self._height(curr_node.left)
        hright_subtree = self._height(curr_node.right)

        if hleft_subtree - hright_subtree in [-1,0,1]:
            return self._isBSTBalanced(curr_node.left) and self._isBSTBalanced(curr_node.right)
        else:
            return False

    def balance_factor(self):
        if self.root is not None:
            return self._balance_factor(self.root)
        else:
            return 0

    def _balance_factor(self, curr_node):
        if curr_node is None:
            return

        hleft_subtree = self._height(curr_node.left)
        hright_subtree = self._height(curr_node.right)

        b_factor = hleft_subtree - hright_subtree
        return b_factor

    def BalanceTree(self):
        if self.isBSTBalanced() == False:
            return self._rebalance(self.root)
        

    def _rebalance(self, curr_node):
        if curr_node is None:
            return None
        curr_node.left = self._rebalance(curr_node.left)
        curr_node.right = self._rebalance(curr_node.right)
        curr_node.height = 1 + max(self._height(curr_node.left), self._height(curr_node.right))
        #print(curr_node.height)
        if self._balance_factor(curr_node) > 1 and self._balance_factor(curr_node.left) >= 0:
            #left heavy subtree
            return self._rotate_right(curr_node)
        if self._balance_factor(curr_node) < -1 and self._balance_factor(curr_node.right) <= 0:
            #right heavy subtree
            return self._rotate_left(curr_node)
        if self._balance_factor(curr_node) < 0 and self._balance_factor(curr_node.right) > 0:
            self._rotate_right(curr_node.right)
            return self._rotate_left(curr_node)
        if self._balance_factor(curr_node) > 0 and self._balance_factor(curr_node.left) < 0:
            self._rotate_left(curr_node.left)
            return self._rotate_right(curr_node)
        return curr_node


    def _rotate_left(self, oldRoot):
        newRoot = oldRoot.right #the newRoot is the right child of the previous root
        oldRoot.right = newRoot.left #replacing right child of the old root with the left child of the new
        if newRoot.left is not None:
            newRoot.left.parent = oldRoot
        newRoot.parent = oldRoot.parent
        if oldRoot == self.root:
            self.root = newRoot
        else:
            if oldRoot.parent.left is oldRoot: #Checking isLeftChild
                oldRoot.parent.left = newRoot
            else:
                oldRoot.parent.right = newRoot

        newRoot.left = oldRoot
        oldRoot.parent = newRoot
        
        oldRoot.height = 1 + max(self._height(oldRoot.left), self._height(oldRoot.right))
        newRoot.height = 1 + max(self._height(newRoot.left), self._height(newRoot.right))
        
        return newRoot

    def _rotate_right(self, oldRoot):
        newRoot = oldRoot.left #the newRoot is the left child of the previous root
        oldRoot.left = newRoot.right #replacing left child of the old root with the right child of the new
        if newRoot.right is not None:
            newRoot.right.parent = oldRoot
        newRoot.parent = oldRoot.parent
        if oldRoot == self.root:
            self.root = newRoot
        else:
            if oldRoot.parent.right is oldRoot: #Checking isRightChild
                oldRoot.parent.right = newRoot
            else:
                oldRoot.parent.left = newRoot

        newRoot.right = oldRoot
        oldRoot.parent = newRoot
        
        oldRoot.height = 1 + max(self._height(oldRoot.left), self._height(oldRoot.right))
        newRoot.height = 1 + max(self._height(newRoot.left), self._height(newRoot.right))
        
        return newRoot
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = BST()
    obj.insert('Basic-Instinct', 0)
    obj.insert('The-Dreamers', 1) 
    obj.insert('Saint-Laurent', 2)
    obj.insert('Pierrot-le-Fou', 3)
    obj.insert('Contempt', 4)
    obj.insert('Before-Sunrise', 5)
    obj.insert('Cold-War', 8)
    
    obj.display_keys(obj.root) #displays a visual representation of our tree, albeit rotated by 90 degrees
    print()
    print("isBSTBalanced:", obj.isBSTBalanced())
    obj.BalanceTree()
    print("isBSTBalanced:", obj.isBSTBalanced()) #After executing BalanceTree(), isBSTBalanced still returns False
    print()
    obj.display_keys(obj.root)
```

**Progress:** Revamped `_isBSTBalanced` method so that it visits every node recursively and not just the root node. The final outcome, however, remains the same.

**Progress:** I was able to identify one of the major issues being that while I was calling `_rotate_left` and `_rotate_right` methods in the `_rebalance` method, I was not returning them. In addition to this, I was not recursively visiting the left and right subtrees of `curr_node`, which was initially set to the root of the tree, to be able to traverse the tree in a bottom up manner. I have resolved this too. I have added a display_keys method which allows us to visualize the tree, albeit rotated by 90 degrees. I'm updating the code and prompt in this post accordingly. The problem that still remains is that I have to call the `BalanceTree()` method more than once in some cases for `isBSTBalanced` to return True.

Comment: The problem should be reproducible. Please provide code that builds a (small) tree and calls (a minimum number of) methods demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I see in the linked code several unrelated issues, but one important one is that `self.isBSTBalanced()` will give false positives. I suggest you test that function alone, without the topic of *rebalancing*. If you test it well, you will find it is not correct. You can then focus your question on that aspect.

Comment: @trincot There may very well be unrelated issues considering I am a student and still learning. I appreciate you taking the time to look at the linked code but could you elaborate how self.isBSTBalanced() might give false positives since I intend for it to simply take a node, visit it's left and right subtrees, get their heights and subtract them and since I'm passing self.root as the initial parameter, it will recursively visit each node to check if that node is balanced?

Comment: I don't see that recursive process happening in our code. The only time that `_isBSTBalanced` is called, it is with the root node. That is an issue. Did you test your code for correctly identifying a tree is balanced? Including tests in your development is an important aspect.

Comment: @trincot I've made the necessary changes to fix _isBSTBalanced and updated the linked code but if you run the code, you'll see that the resultant tree after balancing isn't well, balanced, for _isBSTBalanced still returns False.

Comment: I should mention that rebalancing is only efficient if you do it at the time of insertion and deletion, so to *keep* a tree balanced. When you start with an arbitrary tree, you'll need to (1) use recursion to balance subtrees at all levels, and (2) when an actual rotation happens, you should revisit the parent nodes to verify they need rebalancing again. This is a very inefficient process. Anyway, in your code there is no recursion, so you cannot hope to correctly balance your tree.  But I would stop looking further, and instead work on **keeping** your tree balanced from the start.

Comment: @trincot I understand your point but my assignment dictates that I have to balance an already existing binary search tree. I have updated my question prompt as per your request and I hope that it makes it easier to pinpoint the problem in my code.

Comment: OK, but then I would suggest a different approach than using rotations. It will be more efficient. Would that fit with the requirements?

Comment: @trincot No, the requirements state that I have to use either AVL or Red-Black tree for the balancing.

Comment: Then I will pass on answering, as that will be very inefficient, and I don't like providing inefficient answers. Sorry.

Comment: @trincot I understand, I thank you regardless for taking the time to indulge in this discourse with me and for providing your valuable opinion. I wish I could implement a better and more efficient approach but for the purposes of this assignment, I'm afraid that choice is not in my hands.